# How to solve Error while reading a CSV file in R

Tags: r

hey guys im a beginner in R and want to read a csv file, but I get errors.

I tried this:

```
read.csv("unit_values_feudal.csv",colClasses = c("character","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric"))
```

got this error:

```
error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :    scan() expected 'a real', got '"'
```

added a screen of the file:

[image: csv.file]

Comment: Try `readr::read_csv("unit_values_feudal.csv")`

Comment: You can also delete the commas, and than resave the .csv

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the second argument *colClasses* and R will read the CSV.

Here is something you can try:

`read.csv("unit_values_feudal.csv")`.

Furthermore, as some have pointed out, you probably might want to remove the commas before and after your *numbers*, and the code you have written will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to check the csv file in Notepad rather than excel, I get a feeling that you are not importing the csv into excel using the right delimiter.

Other than that, I think `read.csv("unit_values_feudal.csv")` will just work.